# Mysql query a column with a not default DATE field

Tags: mysql, date, select, format, default

Hello pretty straight forward question here.

MySQL's default DATE field format is YYYY-MM-DD  20/07/2019 
but what if i have a column with a different format as  DD/MM/YYYY  14/10/2021

How to manage a different date format in the below query?

SELECT *
FROM requests
WHERE submited > date_sub(now(), interval 1 week);

thanks
Marco

Comment: Do you store as `VARCHAR` 14/10/2021, instead of `DATE`

Comment: Use STR_TO_DATE() and convert string value to DATE value.

Comment: @ProGu The column is a varchar(10)

Answer (score 1):

As Akina suggested,

> Use STR_TO_DATE() and convert string value to DATE value

```
SELECT *
FROM requests
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(submited, '%d/%m/%Y') > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

It's really not a good idea to store date as VARCHAR, and even worse it's not in yyyy-mm-dd format.
You can't even use the values directly for basic sorting, `14/10/2021` is after `24/10/2020`, but for string comparison they are reversed.